Screen streaming in any program does not work
Screen streaming in any program does not work.
I have installed xdg-desktop-portal and all the necessary libraries. But when I try to start broadcasting in discord, for example, I get 2 messages from pipewire at once, and after I select the entire screen, the pipewire session opens for a split second and then closes immediately.
Although I can see my screen in the preview.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04. I've also seen the problem on Arch Linux.
System info:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-04-30 18:50:45

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              MSI MS-7817
- **Memory:**                                      16.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i5-4690K × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    AMD R5 340X
- **Graphics 1:**                                  Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
- **Disk Capacity:**                               420.1 GB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            V1.9
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               46
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.8.0-31-generic


